# codeigniter template header white Data

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, header

how can I embed a foreach with my header?
I have already tried as in the code.
But with the output I get only "Undefined variable: header_warenkorbs" raus.
Although I am involved in the controller with the value data.

What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
<?php
class Warenkorb extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }

        public function header()
            {
                $data['header_warenkorbs'] = $this->Admin_model->header_warenkorbs();
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                // $this->load->view('test/index');
                // $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
    }
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Warenkorb_model extends CI_Model
    {
        public function header_warenkorbs()
            {
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('db_artikel');
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $query->result_array();
            }
    }
```

View:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn-lg" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><span  class="cart-items-count"><span class=" notification-counter">243</span></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart" role="menu">
            <?php foreach($header_warenkorbs as $warenkorb): ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="item">
                        <span class="item-left">
                            <span class="item-info">
                                <span>Item name</span>
                                <span>23$</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="item-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right">x</button>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a class="text-center" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>warenkorb/index">Warenkorb</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the url you are hitting? Also, you are looking for a method in `Admin_model` but you haven't loaded it. You are Calling the method `header_warenkorbs()` that's defined in `Warenkorb_model`. Turn error reporting on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is a typo or you're not showing us something the problem could be with this line.

```
$data['header_warenkorbs'] = $this->Admin_model->header_warenkorbs();
```

The model code you show is `Warenkorb_model` not `Admin_model`. Seems like the above code should maybe be

```
$data['header_warenkorbs'] = $this->Warenkorb_model->header_warenkorbs();
```

You don't show where you load the model.  It is loaded somewhere... right?  It is common practice to load models in the constructor of the Controller that uses the model.

```
class Warenkorb extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('Warenkorb_model');
    }

    // other code
}
```

Do you realize you are not actually doing anything with the `$header_warenkorbs` in your `foreach` loop? You never use `$warenkorb`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to echo it (example:)

```
<?php
 echo '<table>
        <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td> .$name.</td>
        </tr>
       </table>';
```

?>

just edit it to your needs, im too lazy